# Can i save an html collection in one var using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have the following html object : [element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssBVc.png)

I just want to save the value in a variable. I tried using

```
var result = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("glyphicon-ok")[0].getAttribute('value');
alert(result);
```

But return me null object. How can i save the element of this list in my var using javascript. The element is.

> glyphicon.glyphicon-ok.positive-color

Important, check this image to check the html collection i'm trying save using javascript:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssBVc.png)

Comment: What is this `value` you want? Spans don't have values

Comment: Sorry not value i want to save the object to know which object is this is a html collection and i want to save this object or the attribute or any thing else that let me recognize it

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector to pass CSS selector inside and get the first element of the page selected by the CSS selector (if you want to get all the array, you can use querySelectorAll instead) like that:

```js
let result = document.querySelector('glyphicon.glyphicon-ok.positive-color').value;
alert(result);
```

**Edit: if it returns a null value, it's because your element doesn't have the attribute "value" set...**